# How to check the value of a variable in an Azure ARM Template using Visual Studio

Tags: azure, variables, visual-studio-2013, arm, iaas

I'm using visual studio and want to check the output of a variable in an Azure ARM template before deploying? in the below example I want to check the contents of the variable "connectionstring" Is there a way of displaying the value currently held in here using Visual Studio?

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "username": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "password": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "connectionstring":  "[concat('Name=', parameters('username'), parameters('password'))]"
},
    "resources": [ ],
    "outputs": { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Outputs are always processes after all the deployments in the template are done. The only way to achieve this is use 2 separate templates, but you will need a script for that. Visual studio can't do that for you.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply, so checking values of variables in visual studio cant be done, are there other tools that can do this for ARM templates?

Comment: no, just like i said, nothing can do that for you. arm templates do not offer anything like debugging or inspection mid "flight". the only way to do this: deploy a template that only outputs your variable. get output in the script. evaluate the output. invoke next template that does real thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can better debug your logs but also struggling to see the variable values.

In your azure pipeline set a variable
system.debug: true
and run with system diagnostics on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#view-vars